# Difference between Instance and Process

Tags: c#, memory

Considering the [`Consistency`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/reliability/reliabilitycontractattribute.cs,945a19cd67768190) enum used in `ReliabilityContract`s

```
public enum Consistency : int
{
    MayCorruptProcess   = 0,
    MayCorruptAppDomain = 1,
    MayCorruptInstance  = 2,
    WillNotCorruptState = 3,
}
```

- **What is the difference between a `"Process"` and an `"Instance"`?**
- How do I know / how can I find out whether my code potentially corrupts the *instance*, *AppDomain* or the *process*?

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.consistency?view=netframework-4.7.2?

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen I did; they state "limit state corruption to the current instance" and "corrupt the process" but I don't know what the current instance is as opposed to the current process.

Comment: The instance is the object to which the contract is applied. For example - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,268 . The process is the entire running OS process.

Comment: @mjwills oh, that really explains it. I guess I was barking up the wrong tree, thinking "current instance" refered to the current process / thread etc.